# Websockets with Tornado: Get access from the "outside" to send messages to clients

Tags: python, websocket, webserver, tornado

I'm starting to get into WebSockets as way to push data from a server to connected clients. Since I use python to program any kind of logic, I looked at Tornado so far. The snippet below shows the most basic example one can find everywhere on the Web:

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print 'new connection'
        self.write_message("Hello World")

    def on_message(self, message):
        print 'message received %s' % message
        self.write_message('ECHO: ' + message)

    def on_close(self):
    print 'connection closed'


application = tornado.web.Application([
  (r'/ws', WSHandler),
])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

As it is, this works as intended. However, I can't get my head around how can get this "integrated" into the rest of my application. In the example above, the WebSocket only sends something to the clients as a reply to a client's message. How can I access the WebSocket from the "outside"? For example, to notify all currently connected clients that some kind event has occured -- and this event is NOT any kind of message from a client. Ideally, I would like to write somewhere in my code something like:

```
websocket_server.send_to_all_clients("Good news everyone...")
```

How can I do this? Or do I have a complete misundersanding on how WebSockets (or Tornado) are supposed to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

You need to keep track of all the clients that connect. So:

```
clients = []

def send_to_all_clients(message):
    for client in clients:
        client.write_message(message)

class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        send_to_all_clients("new client")
        clients.append(self)

    def on_close(self):
        clients.remove(self)
        send_to_all_clients("removing client")

    def on_message(self, message):
        for client in clients:
            if client != self:
                client.write_message('ECHO: ' + message)
```

Comment: Hans, thanks! Yeah, I found this solution somewhere. But firstly, it was argued that using a global variable for that is not a nice way. And secondly, even with that I don't know how to proceed. I suppose that somewhere I have to loop over all `clients` and for each client call the `write_message` method. But where to put the loop. When I start the script, everything seems to be blocked. Could you extend my initial example to make a full example with your approach, including a loop over the client array. That would be awesome!

Comment: I have added a method to send a message to all clients and a few examples how to call that message.

Comment: I see, but still, `send_to_all_clients` is called from within the WSHandler class. How can I now invoke this method from basically everywhere to integrate in a larger application? Perhaps I just have a complete misunderstanding about WebSockets.

Comment: You can call the `send_to_all_clients` from anywhere you want.

Comment: That might expose my weaknesses in Python :). But what doesn't work is, e.g., a 2nd script with `from ... import send_to_all_clients` and then `send_to_all_clients('External message')`. It's just not the same scope, the `clients` array is always empty when called like this. Can you make a concrete example of "you can call it from anywhere you want"?

Comment: Well your python should just work. But maybe your weakness is not so much Python as Javascript. Can you show the code for the clients that connect to your websocket server?

Comment: In fact, it was my misconception with WebSocket servers or at least Tornado. The straightforward way to trigger the sending of a meesage from an application is to let the application connect to Tornado using a dedicated Handler, i.e., making the application basically something like a "special client". But thanks a lot for you effort, it certainly helped me to spot my problem!

Comment: Since I have my client continuously listening to the server in a loop, as it is mentioned here http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/websocket.html#client-side-support. I am not able to get multiple instances of clients to connect to the server using the above mentioned process of using a list.. The second client always waits for the first client process to end before I can read messages from the server.. is there any way around this?

Answer (score 11):

This is building on Hans Then's example. Hopefully it helps you understand how you can have your server initiate communication with your clients without the clients triggering the interaction.

Here's the server:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import datetime
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web



class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    clients = []
    def open(self):
        print 'new connection'
        self.write_message("Hello World")
        WSHandler.clients.append(self)

    def on_message(self, message):
        print 'message received %s' % message
        self.write_message('ECHO: ' + message)

    def on_close(self):
        print 'connection closed'
        WSHandler.clients.remove(self)

    @classmethod
    def write_to_clients(cls):
        print "Writing to clients"
        for client in cls.clients:
            client.write_message("Hi there!")


application = tornado.web.Application([
  (r'/ws', WSHandler),
])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_timeout(datetime.timedelta(seconds=15), WSHandler.write_to_clients)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I made the client list a class variable, rather than global. I actually wouldn't mind using a global variable for this, but since you were concerned about it, here's an alternative approach.

And here's a sample client:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import tornado.websocket
from tornado import gen 

@gen.coroutine
def test_ws():
    client = yield tornado.websocket.websocket_connect("ws://localhost:8888/ws")
    client.write_message("Testing from client")
    msg = yield client.read_message()
    print("msg is %s" % msg)
    msg = yield client.read_message()
    print("msg is %s" % msg)
    msg = yield client.read_message()
    print("msg is %s" % msg)
    client.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().run_sync(test_ws)
```

You can then run the server, and have two instances of the test client connect. When you do, the server prints this:

```
bennu@daveadmin:~$ ./torn.py 
new connection
message received Testing from client
new connection
message received Testing from client
<15 second delay>
Writing to clients
connection closed
connection closed
```

The first client prints this:

```
bennu@daveadmin:~$ ./web_client.py 
msg is Hello World
msg is ECHO: Testing from client
< 15 second delay>
msg is Hi there! 0
```

And the second prints this:

```
bennu@daveadmin:~$ ./web_client.py 
msg is Hello World
msg is ECHO: Testing from client
< 15 second delay>
msg is Hi there! 1
```

For the purposes of the example, I just had the server send the message to the clients on a 15 second delay, but it could be triggered by whatever you want.

Comment: Dano, thanks a lot! That brings me closer to my goal. But a timer doesn't fit an event-based system. I also cannot see, how I could send the message as parameter instead of always "Hi, there". Your "but it could be triggered by whatever you want" is the really intriguing part for me :). Is there really now way to get an handle on the WebSocket like `ws = WebSocket()` which includes starting the server and then a `ws.write_to_clients(msg)` whenever a event occurred? Isn't that the main idea here? But I couldn't find an example yet.

Comment: What is the "event" you have in mind? My example could be refactored slightly, so that `write_to_clients` is just a function at the top-level of the module, rather than a class method. It could also take a parameter instead of just always using "Hi, there". Then your event handling code can just call that method. Does that make sense?

Comment: I assume your changes would like Hans' modified example with a `send_to_all_clients` method on the top level of the module. But in his example he still invokes this method from within the WSHandler class. But how can I invoke this method from "everywhere"? -- To give an example: Say my application makes complex calculations, and each time a new result is available I want to announce it to all connected clients.

Comment: I don't mean to make the function part of the WSHandler class. Just make it a standalone function at the top level of the module, and use `WSHandler.clients` inside of it instead of `cls.clients`. Then you just call `write_to_clients` from the function doing the calculations.

Comment: Please see my latestet comment to the first answer. I finally spotted my misconception. Thanks a lot for you help getting there!

Comment: This has been an aptly explained answer, the code samples provided are sufficient to understand the idea and even try more things. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hey could you guys check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51635511/python-multiple-tornado-clients-simultaneously-connecting-to-tornado-server, it would be super helpful to get some insight from people who know tornado well!

Answer (score 0):

my solution for this: first add `"if __name__ == '__main__':"` - to the main.py. then import main.py into the websocket module. e.g. (`import main as MainApp`) . it is now possible to call a function in 'main.py' from within the ws.py/WebSocketHandler-function. - inside the Handler pass the message like so:
`MainApp.function(message)`

i dunno if this is the opposite of elegant but it works for me.

..plus create and import a custom 'config.py' (thats looks like: `someVar = int(0)` ) into the 'mainApp.py' .. like so: `import config as cfg` --> now you can alter variables with `cfg.someVar = newValue` from inside the function in 'main.py' that once was called by the Handler from 'ws.py'.