# WebSocket Threading using Global Variables

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket, tornado

I'm trying to create a WebSocket server using the very popular [Tornado server for Python](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch2.1/websocket.html), but I'm having an issue creating a global-scoped `self` variable in order to write data to the web socket outside the class.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562465/websockets-with-tornado-get-access-from-the-outside-to-send-messages-to-clien) solved my problem exactly, but I wanted to take it a step further and wrap the whole thing in a thread.

This is my socket:

```
wss = []

class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True

    def open(self):
        print ('New connection established.')
        if self not in wss:
            wss.append(self)

    def on_message(self, message):
        print ('Received message: %s' % message)

    def on_close(self):
        print ('Connection closed.')
        if self in wss:
            wss.remove(self)
```

This is the method that is outside of the class that writes to the socket:

```
def write_data(message):
    for ws in wss:
        print ("Sending: %s" % message)
        ws.write_message(message);
```

This is the threaded server class:

```
class ServerThread(threading.Thread):

    def run(self):
        print ("Starting server.")
        http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
        http_server.listen(4045)
        main_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
        main_loop.start()

    def send_data(self, message):
        write_data(message);
```

The strange thing is, when the code is not wrapped in a `Thread` class, the write method works fine. In the code above, when I call:

```
server_thread = ServerThread()
server_thread.start()
server_thread.send_data("Ping!")
```

nothing happens. The method `write_data(message)` is entered, but evidently `wss[]` is empty.

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated!

**Update:**

I've been continuously looking into this problem to no avail. Another strange thing: `New connection established.` never prints to the console making me think that the socket is never appended to the list rather than it being a variable scoping problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. https://gist.github.com/binux/2e1c7b3b2b8de18f950c  Are there any other threads in your program? tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance() is a process shared IOLoop object, it's not good start it from a thread.

Comment: This is what I have so far: http://pastebin.com/S4hkDRqg
The print statement in the `send_data(self, message)` does not work as expected and the socket does not write `Ping!`

Comment: You are not supposed to send_data after thread.start immediately. As no websocket is connected yet.

Comment: During testing I had `time.sleep(2)` between the two lines. It unfortunately still doesn't work.

Comment: Could you confirm that `New connection established.` before `send_data`?

Comment: `New connection established.` never prints and I have no idea why. This might be the source of the problem.

Comment: Have you connected to server from client(browser)? `new WebSocket('ws://localhost:4044/')`

Comment: Yes, I've connected from a client in the browser. I know the web socket listener works simply because it's an easy implementation and I reused code from a previous project that worked.

Comment: Seems that port 4045 is restricted. Can't connected by websocket. You can get a error message from browser console. I can't reproduce this issue with your code (with port changed and some typo fix)

Comment: I finally figured it out. I changed the port value (not sure if that mattered) and threw the `send_data(self, message)` in a `while True` loop. For whatever reason, the browser always seems to miss the first couple of packets and the timing between loading the client and actually reading data sent from the server is finicky. If `write_socket` is called in `open` everything works fine, but if the call is made outside the method, it seems to miss the first few calls. Thanks so much for your help and your time. If you want to post an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: would you please update the port in your question, as I think it's the main problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to use port 4045 for HTTP/WebSocket service, as it's blocked by browser. You may get an error message from browser:

```
Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The port 4045 is not allowed.
```

http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/netlib/PortBanning.html
http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203772